# Investment advice data dump analysis

Tags: database, web-scraping, analysis, dump, finance

For my year-end pet project, I'd like to analyze investment advices and their correlation to the stock market performance.

The problem is, where do I get the dump of investment advice data (free) ? 
something like stackoverflow.com data dump will be nice.

Or maybe it's easier to do distributed crawling and crawl the public finance webpages for investment advices?

Investment advice is buy/sell advice for stocks/forex, issued by institution/investment advisor.

Answer (score 2):

You could try extracting advices from twitter:

http://wefollow.com/twitter/stocks
http://wefollow.com/twitter/trading

I can give you 3.5 years of daily buy/neutral/sell public (but hard to find) advice from a major bank on around 10 Forex major pairs, if you promise to share the analysis you make on them with me :) My analysis shows that following all of their advices was extremely profitable during the late 2008 global collapse, but mostly flat before/after that:
[image]

X axis: time in days
Y axis: profit in points (pips)

Comment: Thanks for the links. Was thinking about extracting data from twitter through http://stocktwits.com/application

Comment: I'm also crawling and storing stocktwits data. You don't need theirs API through, you can just reverse engineer theirs All stream page (http://stocktwits.com/streams/all). Another thing to do is to create a twitter account and follow the most important 2000 financial ids then use the stream API to get the twits.

Comment: I don't suppose institutions use stocktwits.com do they? It will be hard to follow the 'smart' money using stocktwits.com

Comment: @portoalet You'd be surprised. http://thenextweb.com/uk/2010/12/16/investment-fund-set-to-use-twitter-to-judge-emotion-in-the-market/

Answer (score 1):

Most analyst recommendations are distributed through a product called [IBES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institutional_Brokers%27_Estimate_System). I believe that it is available for a significant amount of money through Thomson Reuters. If you are interested in this data set they have a second one that is called something like "As Was" which has the original recommendations and not what the analysts updated it to later.

Answer (score 0):

Not free, but has a free trial: http://www.zacksdata.com/zacks-data-api

*(Disclosure: My company manages this API)*